# How to get the number of days of difference between two dates in awk

Tags: awk

I need to read a date format from a file in **awk**.
Each line in my file has two date data one in the first element and the other one in the second element.The format is `day/month/year`.
Is there a way of comparison between two dates in awk. 
For instance, I need to get 2 days as an answer if I have `03/05/2015` and `05/05/2015`.

---

Sorry for not providing sample input/output for my question. The input is actually the same as Akshay described. 
I have a file in which each line starts with two dates

```
03/05/2015   05/05/2015
```

corresponding to start and end of process (the second one always happens after the first one). 
I do a hard coding using awk to read information about two dates.
It is not the optimal solution but I needed to obtain some results by yesterday.
Simply, I extract day, month and year of each date and compute how many days they are far apart.
 I also do a simple check to see if the corresponding year is a leap year or not.

```
awk'{

D1= int(substr($1,1,2));   
D2= int(substr($2,1,2));    
M1= int(substr($1,4,2));    
M2= int(substr($2,4,2));    
Y1 = int(substr($1,7,4));    
Y2 = int(substr($2,7,4));

leap1 = ((Y1-2008)%4)?1:0;

leap2 = ((Y2-2008)%4)?1:0;

cnt1 = 0;

ii = 1; 

while(ii<D1) {
if(ii==2) cnt1+=(leap1+28); else{if((ii==1)||(ii==3)||(ii==5)||(ii==7)||(ii==8)||(ii==10)||(ii==12)) cnt1+=31; if((ii==4)||(ii==6)||(ii==9)||(ii==11)) cnt1+=30;}ii++;}

cnt2 = 0;

ii = 1; 

while(ii<D2)

 {
if(ii==2) cnt2+=(leap2+28); else{if((ii==1)||(ii==3)||(ii==5)||(ii==7)||(ii==8)||(ii==10)||(ii==12)) cnt2+=31; if((ii==4)||(ii==6)||(ii==9)||(ii==11)) cnt2+=30;}ii++;}

Day = cnt2-cnt1+D2-D1+(Y2-Y1)*365;

}`
```

I know this is far from optimal but again I needed to produce something quick.

Comment: It is good to show what you tried so far, together with a more clear input / desired output. Give a read to [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your input looks something like this

**Input file**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat file
03/05/2015 05/05/2015
06/03/2015 08/05/2015
```

**Script - GAWK Specific**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat date_diff_gawk.awk
function date2time(date,     a)
{
        split(date, a, /\//)
        return mktime(a[3] " " a[2] " " a[1] " 0 0 0")
}
function abs(n)
{
        return n<0 ? -n : n
}
function diff_days(d1,d2,    delta)
{
        delta = date2time(d1) - date2time(d2)
        return int(abs(delta)/86400)
}
{
    print $0, diff_days($2,$1) " days"
}
```

**Script - Any awk**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat date_diff_anyawk.awk
BEGIN {
    split("0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334",D,/,/)
}
function dfm(date,   a,year,month,day)
{
        split(date,a,/\//)
        year = a[3]; month = a[2]+0; day = a[1]
        date = ((year - 1970) * 365.25) + D[month] + day - 1
        if ((year % 4) == 0 && month > 2) { date = date + 1}
        return (date * 86400 - (25200))/86400
}
function abs(n)
{
        return n<0 ? -n : n
}
function date_diff(d1,d2)
{
    return  abs(dfm(d1)-dfm(d2))
}
{
    print $0,date_diff($2,$1) " days"
}
```

**Execution**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk -f date_diff_gawk.awk file
03/05/2015 05/05/2015 2 days
06/03/2015 08/05/2015 63 days

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk -f date_diff_anyawk.awk file
03/05/2015 05/05/2015 2 days
06/03/2015 08/05/2015 63 days

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ echo '06/03/2015 31/05/2015' | awk -f date_diff_any_awk.awk 
06/03/2015 31/05/2015 86 days
```

Comment: Very nice. Probably requires GNU awk for the time functions.

Answer (score -2):

actually I found a way to compare two dates using `substr()`. It is not the most efficient way but it seems to be working.

I simply extract day, month and year of two dates and the convert them to "int" by using int(..). This way I can extract the difference between two dates.

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely that this would be the best approach but without sample input and expected output we can't help you.

Comment: How do you know which month has how many days in your code (especially if Feb has 28 or 29 days)?